# Cumulocity - Registering Raspberry Pi 3B - Agent not able to connect

Tags: raspberry-pi3, cumulocity

Using Raspberry Pi 3B. Performed the following steps:
1)I installed the agent as per instructions.
2) Updated the config cumulocity.properties file with the correct host.
3) Tried registering the device by putting in the serial number on the cumulocity site.

Was not able to register.

4) Ran another instance of the agent in the debug mode by outputting debug logs on the console. This time the agent was able to communicate and registration was complete.

5) Stopped the instance and saw that the original agent was still not able to communicate. The cumulocity site showed the "Push Connection" was active from the cumulocity site but the "Send connection" was offline.

Question: Is this the normal behavior?

## In the logs, which are located at /var/log/messages, I am seeing the following logged:

## May  8 14:20:41 raspberrypi logger: 14:20:41.996 [main] WARN  c8y.lx.agent.PropUtils - Configuration file ./cfg/cumulocity-config.properties cannot be read, assuming empty configuration

The file "./cfg/cumulocity-config.properties" does not exist - seems like this is hard coded in the agent code. The property file used is "./cfg/cumulocity.properties".

Is this a bug which is causing the agent not being able to talk to the host as the property file does not exist? Anyone else encountering the same problem and can share workaround / resolution?

Thanks.

Comment: This question was for the cumulocity developers using Raspi as a device and not for PI specifically.

Answer (score 1):

This specific warning is not a bug. It's normal on first boot.

How exactly did you run the second instance? Running multiple instance of the agent can result in unexpected behavior.

Furthermore regarding the send connection. If you have no supported sensors connected to the Pi, it will remain inactive as no measurements are being send.

Comment: I first stopped the running agent from the init.d directory. Then I used the c8y-agent-debug.sh script to run the agent, modifying it to display logs on the terminal. I saw both the send and push channels active and messages getting exchanged. I was able to complete registration only this way and establish connectivity with Cum platform. After a while the "send" channel became inactive again.

Comment: To your comment on the "send" channel remaining inactive as no sensor data was sent, I was wondering how would we monitor the status of the raspi device itself, if it was up or not. I was thinking the agent was designed to send those messages as well - although not sure about that.

Comment: Theoretically you can write a simple ping driver, that sends a Cumulocity ping message every RequiredInterval. But it is not in the platform currently.
The cumulocity ping is just an empty PUT:

    PUT /inventory/managedObjects/{{deviceId}}
    Content-Type: application/json
    body:{}

Comment: @ms2015 forgot to notify you